# en C++ las cadenas std::string son de longitud dinámica o fija

Tags: array, string, c++17

Estoy aprendiendo C++ desde hace dos semanas y tengo una duda sobre las cadenas de texto encontradas en el encabezado <  string  > , la pregunta es si estas cadenas son de longitud fija o pueden crecer concatenándoles contenido.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


void imprimir(std::string cdn){
    std::cout << cdn << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    

    std::string parrafo[5];
    
    parrafo[0]="Esta es la primera linea de un parrafo";
    parrafo[1]="EL gallo canta por la mañana";
    parrafo[2]="Hola mundo";
    parrafo[3]="frase que no tiene sentido";
    parrafo[4]="Esta es la ultima linea de un parrafo"
    
    imprimir(parrafo[0]);
    imprimir(parrafo[1]);
    imprimir(parrafo[2]);
    imprimir(parrafo[3]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Mi interés es crear un arreglo 1D de tipo string para representar líneas de un documento en forma de un párrafo, pero tiene líneas de diferentes longitudes y lo que quiero saber es si esto dará un problema mas adelante.

Como he leído que los arrays almacenan datos de tamaño constante como por ejemplo un array de números flotantes solo puede almacenar valores de una misma longitud de bits y por eso me sale la duda sobre los strings de longitudes variadas.

Realmente si pueden explicarme como funcionan los strings por dentro agradeceria mucho.

```
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    std::string cadena ="Hola mundo";
    cadena = "otro texto";
    
    return 0;
}
```

En el código de arriba declaré una cadena y luego le cambio el valor, el valor anterior se perdió o quedó en la memoria perdido, se sobrescribió en el mismo lugar de memoria o qué pasó realmente.

Comment: ¿ Has leido [**la documentación**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) ?

Answer (score 2):

> la pregunta es si estas cadenas son de longitud fija o pueden crecer concatenándoles contenido

Pueden crecer concatenándoles contenido. Por eso disponen de las siguientes funciones:

- [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert): Inserta caracteres.
- [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back): Añade un carácter al final.
- [`append`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append): Añade una cadena al final.
- [`operator +=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D): Añade caracteres o una cadena al final.

Este programa:

```
std::string perro = "Perro";

std::cout << perro << '\n';

perro.insert(1, 1, 'u');
std::cout << perro << '\n';

perro.push_back('s');
std::cout << perro << '\n';

perro.append(" a la parrilla");
std::cout << perro << '\n';

perro += " que ricos!";
std::cout << perro << '\n';
```

Genera la siguiente salida:

> ```
> Perro
> Puerro
> Puerros
> Puerros a la parrilla
> Puerros a la parrilla que ricos!
> ```

---

> Como he leído que los arrays almacenan datos de tamaño constante como por ejemplo un array de números flotantes solo puede almacenar valores de una misma longitud de bits

Tienes un lío de conceptos muy grande:

- *Array* es el nombre de un concepto Y el nombre de un contenedor de datos.

  - Se conoce como formación (o arreglo, o en inglés *array*) una colección de datos del mismo tipo cuya cantidad de datos es fija y cuyos datos se almacenan en memoria de manera anexa.
  - El contenedor `std::array` es un contenedor diseñado para ayudar a manejar formaciones.
- Confundes el tamaño del contenedor con el tamaño de los datos. Un contenedor de datos sólo almacena datos del mismo tipo, por ello los datos serán todos del mismo tamaño. La cantidad de datos que almacena el contenedor puede ser fija o variable dependiendo del tipo de contenedor.